# How to fetch data from ajax post call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to fetch data from ajax post. My ajax file is as follows:

```
$('#login').on('click',
    function (e) {
        // alert("login ic clicked");
        e.preventDefault();
        // var contents = $(this).serialize(); 
        // alert("hello in success");

        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        alert(username);
        $.ajax(
        {

            url:'check_login.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:"json",
            data: "{'username':'" + username + "','password':'" + password + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success:function(data)
            {
                // $('#addTitleStatus').removeClass('show alert-success alert-danger');
                alert("i am in success");
                if(data.success)
                {
                    alert("data is ok" + data.result);

                    // $('#addTitleStatus').addClass('alert-success');
                    // $('#addTitleStatus').html(data.result);
                    // $('#addTitleStatus').addClass('show');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(data);
                    // $('#addTitleStatus').addClass('alert-danger');
                    // $('#addTitleStatus').html(data.result);
                    // $('#addTitleStatus').addClass('show');
                }
            },
        }
            );
        // alert("Wfah");
    });
```

My check_login.php file is as follows:

```
<?php 

    $json  = array('success' => false, 
                    'result' => 0
                    );
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    json_decode($username);

    $json['result'] = $username;
    $json['success'] = "true";
    echo json_encode($json);



 ?>
```

Firefox shows following:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: username in
>   **/opt/lampp/htdocs/ambition/check_login.php** on line  **6** {"success":"true","result":null}

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what do you get if you add var_dump($_POST) at the top of check_login.php file ? Track the AJAX request using Firebug or Chrome Developer plugin maybe ?

Comment: I am using firefox. Every thing works fine. Only check_login.php gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data:` option should be either an object or a string in the form `param=value&param=value`, not a JSON string. The object method is generally preferred, so that jQuery will encode it properly. So it should be:

```
data: { username: username, password: password },
```

or

```
data: 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password),
```

and get rid of the `contentType:` option.

Comment: Thank you sir. works fine.. how can I implement it in param=value&param=value form?

Comment: I've added that. Now forget about it and always use the first form.